How to set default Reactable options?
Is there a way to set default reactable table options e.g. (compact = T and striped = T) throughout instead of copy/pasting the same options for each reactable table?
It looks like you can set the default theme using options(reactable.theme = reactableTheme()), but not sure about the above options e.g. (compact = T and striped = T).

A workaround would be to set the options and then define your own table-making function that calls those preset options:
options(reactable.compact = T,
        reactable.searchable = T,
        reactable.bordered = T,
        reactable.striped = T,
        reactable.highlight = T)

create_table <- \(data){
  data_react <- reactable(
    data,
    bordered = getOption("reactable.bordered"),
    compact = getOption("reactable.compact"),
    searchable = getOption("reactable.searchable"),
    striped = getOption("reactable.striped"),
    highlight = getOption("reactable.highlight")
  )
  
  return(data_react)
  
}

create_table(data = df1)

You can reuse the function as you please. Hope this helps!
